# Wrap adjacent <p> elements into a <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Is it possible to select all `<p>` elements that are next to each other and wrap them in a `<div>`?

E.g. I have

```
<div class="content">
  <p>one</p>
  <p>two</p>
  <h2> not p</h2>
  <p>three</p>
  <p>four</p>
  <p>five</p>
  <h3>not p</h3>
  <div>not p</div>
  <p>six</p>
 <p>seven</p>
</div>
```

And I would like to get something, like this:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="wrap">
    <p>one</p>
    <p>two</p>
  </div>
  <h2> not p</h2>
  <div class="wrap">
    <p>three</p>
    <p>four</p>
    <p>five</p>
  </div>
  <h3>not p</h3>
  <div>not p</div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <p>six</p>
    <p>seven</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it is. What have you tried, what went wrong or didn’t work? In what way did it not work?

Comment: It is possible. What have you tried already? Have you searched for useful JavaScript and jQuery functions? Have you done research about selectors?

Comment: Read ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the first few paragraphs. We'll help if you have a "specific problem".

Comment: I'm not really sure how to select all those p that are next to each other so i can then call wrap(). function to wrap them in a div.

Comment: https://www.timjensen.us/wrap-sibling-groups-using-jquery/ - basically nextuntil with not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this, is a good starting point:

```js
$(function(){

  const target = 'p',
        invert = ':not(' + target + ')',
        wrap = '<div class="wrapper">',
        breakpoints = $('.content > *'+invert);
    
   breakpoints.each(function(){
        $(this).nextUntil(invert).wrapAll( wrap );
    });
    
   breakpoints.first().prevUntil(invert).wrapAll( wrap );
    
});
```

```css
.wrapper{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="content">
  <p>one</p>
  <p>two</p>
  <h2> not p</h2>
  <p>three</p>
  <p>four</p>
  <p>five</p>
  <h3>not p</h3>
  <div>not p</div>
  <p>six</p>
  <p>seven</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not very useful.  What have you done? Why does this work? And may I suggest cleaning up your formatting / indenting?

Comment: The code is very clear with semantic variable naming,  I'll format it so it looks prettier :)

Comment: The code is clear _to you_.  I'm suggesting it would be clearer to newbies by adding some comments / description.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the algorithm is pretty much straightforward: iterate through array of `<p>` nodes and throw the item into previous `.wrapper` if previous sibling is `.wrapper` itself or create one otherwise:

```js
[...$('p')].forEach((p,i) => 
  $(p).prev().is('.wrapper') && i > 0  ?
  $(p).prev().append(p) : 
  $('<div class="wrapper"></div>').insertBefore(p).append(p))
```

```css
.wrapper {background: lightblue}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><div class="content"><p>one</p><p>two</p><h2> not p</h2><p>three</p><p>four</p><p>five</p><h3>not p</h3><div>not p</div><p>six</p><p>seven</p></div>
```